# include the externs dir in github/closure-compiler/contrib

Tags: google-closure-compiler, clojurescript

On a clojurescript project, I've needed to access contrib/externs/w3c_audio.cljs

I thought if I just wrote it in, google would access it, but I couldn't get that to work. Instead, I went in and just copied the file to my local directory.

Is there a way to not do that? i.e write something in my project.clj that knows I want to get the file in  closure-compiler's contrib/externs?

```
            :externs  ["react/externs/react.js"
                        "externs/custom.js"
                        "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                        "contrib/externs/w3c_audio.js"
                        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project doesn't use any other Clojurescript libraries that requires extra extern files, consider using `fence.core/..` for javascript interop:

https://github.com/myguidingstar/fence

Even if your project does, fence still helps reduce number of extern files to work on